# Editing an external batch config value with batch

Tags: batch-file, external, config, editing

I have a config file named config.conf with the content of:

```
[Config]
password=1234 
usertries=0 
allowterminate=0
```

I want to just edit the usertries value to 5, are there any batch script code that can help me do that

Thanks

Comment: Which scripting languages are you ready to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a little messy, but should work:

```
@echo off
set ConfigFile=config.conf
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "delims=" %%L in (%ConfigFile%) do (
  set "LINE=%%L"
  if "!LINE:~0,10!"=="usertries=" (echo usertries=5) else (echo !LINE!)
)) > %ConfigFile%.new
move /y %ConfigFile%.new %ConfigFile% > nul
```

Basically we're writing each line to a new file, unless it starts with `usertries=`. In which case we just insert our replacement line. Afterwards we move the new file on top of the old one to replace it.

Comment: My config is in a folder named test, so I must put set ConfigFile=test/config.conf right?

Comment: Also can I know what this line does set "LINE=%%L" cause I may change the line number for the usertries

Comment: It's not working, here's my code

    set ConfigFile=test/config.conf
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f %%L in (%ConfigFile%) do (
  set "LINE=%%L"
  if "!LINE:~0,10!"=="usertries=" (echo usertries=0) else (echo !LINE!)
)) > %ConfigFile%.new
move /y %ConfigFile%.new %ConfigFile% > nul

Comment: `test\config.conf` should be correct. Normally Windows doesn't care about `/` or `\`, but the Command Processor does in some instances and does some weird things. `set "LINE=%%L"` just stores the current line in an environment variable so that it can be processed further (you can't grab substrings from a `for` variable).

Comment: I'm not sure what goes wrong for you, it worked in my test. However, you seem to write `usertries=0` into the file instead of `5`.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted it to be 0 now

Comment: Can I like change usertries=0 to a var like usertries=%usertries%

Comment: I think it might be the Line problem, what does "!LINE:~0,10!" mean

Comment: You can, but only if you define the variable before the loop. And `!LINE:~0,10!` grabs the first 10 characters of the `LINE` variable. See `help set` for an explanation.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how your test arrangement is like, config content, whole script, directory etc cause it isn't working on my batch script

Comment: I took the exact contents of `config.conf` you posted in your question. I created that file, put the code above in a batch file in the same folder and ran it. It also works with the config in a subdirectory (and appropriately adapted path to the config file). I would have thought all that to be pretty obvious because there's not much more I can work with here anyway.

Comment: HAH, Removed the ( before the FOR and it works now but it makes a new file called config.conf.new, it doesn't replace the current file

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
::
:: set %1 to value %2 in config.conf
::
SET target=%2&IF NOT DEFINED target ECHO syntax is %0 keyname newvalue&GOTO :EOF 
SET target=Config.conf
MOVE /y %target% %target%.old >NUL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN (%target%.old) DO (
IF /i %%i==%1 (ECHO %%i=%2) ELSE (
IF "%%j"=="" (ECHO %%i) ELSE (ECHO %%i=%%j)
)
) >>%target%
```

With this version, you can change an existing key to a value using

```
thisbatchname existingkey newvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I decided to write a general purpose ini file utility batch script to address this question.

The script will let you retrieve or modify values in an ini-style file.  Its searches are case-insensitive, and it preserves blank lines in the ini file.  In essence, it allows you to interact with an ini file as a sort of very rudimentary database.

```
:: --------------------
:: ini.bat
:: ini.bat /? for usage
:: --------------------

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

goto begin

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 /i item [/v value] [/s section] inifile
echo;
echo Take the following ini file for example:
echo;
echo    [Config]
echo    password=1234
echo    usertries=0
echo    allowterminate=0
echo;
echo To read the "password" value:
echo    %~nx0 /s Config /i password inifile
echo;
echo To change the "usertries" value to 5:
echo    %~nx0 /s Config /i usertries /v 5 inifile
echo;
echo In the above examples, "/s Config" is optional, but will allow the selection of
echo a specific item where the ini file contains similar items in multiple sections.
goto :EOF

:begin
if "%~1"=="" goto usage
for %%I in (item value section found) do set %%I=
for %%I in (%*) do (
    if defined next (
        if !next!==/i set item=%%I
        if !next!==/v set value=%%I
        if !next!==/s set section=%%I
        set next=
    ) else (
        for %%x in (/i /v /s) do if "%%~I"=="%%x" set "next=%%~I"
        if not defined next (
            set "arg=%%~I"
            if "!arg:~0,1!"=="/" (
                1>&2 echo Error: Unrecognized option "%%~I"
                1>&2 echo;
                1>&2 call :usage
                exit /b 1
            ) else set "inifile=%%~I"
        )
    )
)
for %%I in (item inifile) do if not defined %%I goto usage
if not exist "%inifile%" (
    1>&2 echo Error: %inifile% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

if not defined section (
    if not defined value (
        for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (`findstr /i "^%item%\=" "%inifile%"`) do (
            echo(%%I
        )
    ) else (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`findstr /n "^" "%inifile%"`) do (
            set "line=%%I" && set "line=!line:*:=!"
            echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(%item%=%value%
                echo(%value%
            ) || 1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!
        )
    )
) else (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`findstr /n "^" "%inifile%"`) do (
        set "line=%%I" && set "line=!line:*:=!"
        if defined found (
            if defined value (
                echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                    1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(%item%=%value%
                    echo(%value%
                    set found=
                ) || 1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!
            ) else echo(!line! | findstr /i "^%item%\=" >NUL && (
                for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ("!line!") do (
                    echo(%%x
                    exit /b 0
                )
            )
        ) else (
            if defined value (1>>"%inifile%.1" echo(!line!)
            echo(!line! | find /i "[%section%]" >NUL && set found=1
        )
    )
)

if exist "%inifile%.1" move /y "%inifile%.1" "%inifile%">NUL
```

**Example:**

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>type config.conf
[Config]
password=1234
usertries=0
allowterminate=0

[Other]
password=foo

C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /i usertries /v 5 config.conf
5

C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /i usertries config.conf
5

C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /s config /i password /v bar config.conf
bar

C:\Users\me\Desktop>ini /s other /i password /v baz config.conf
baz

C:\Users\me\Desktop>type config.conf
[Config]
password=bar
usertries=5
allowterminate=0

[Other]
password=baz
```